# Clicking on the comment edit button causes multiple inputs to be shown

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, comment-edits

See below gif, as it shows the issue clearly:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When clicking on the edit button, it doesn't actually get rid of the edit link, and clicking it multiple times causes undesired behavior. (This can simply happen if a user double clicks on the edit button by accident.)

Comment: Thanks! I did do a search, and couldn't actually find it.